# Why does the private storage path not match the Cognito user ID? How do I access private level files?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-cli

I am writing to a private S3 bucket. When trying to read the path has a different UUID from my current Cognito user ID. Any ideas why that is? And how do I access those files correctly?

I am trying:

```
import Storage from '@aws-amplify/storage';

const res = await Storage.vault.get('reports/'); 
const res1 = Storage.list(`reports/`, { level: 'private' })
```

On the network tab I can see it adds region as a prefix too: `private/us-east-1:ar15e955-e51d-42f2-8f54-eaff9f47fbb5/reports/`

Similar closed issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/364